# Can we say that there is $P$ such that $P^T AP=B?$

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms, similar-matrices

Consider the quadratic form $Q(v)=v^{t}Av,v=(x,y,z,w)$ where matrix $A$ is given by  \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0  \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
\end{bmatrix}

Then which of the following is true?

1. $Q$ has rank 3.
2. $xy+z^{2}=Q(Pv)$ for some invertible real matrix $P.$
3. $xy+y^{2}+z^{2}=Q(Pv)$ for some real invertible matrix $P.$
4. $x^{2}+y^{2}-zw=Q(Pv)$ for some some real invertible matrix $P.$

From $A$, $Q$ must be having the Rank $4$. So, (1) Must not be true.

if we do $R_3→-1/2R_3$ and $R_4→-1/2R_4$ we get, $$B=\begin{bmatrix}  1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\  0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\  0 & 0 & 0 & -1/2 \\  0 & 0 & -1/2 & 0\\  \end{bmatrix}$$ Can we say that there is $P$ such that $P^T AP=B?$

Comment: One case is when $P$ is orthogonal and $B$ is a diagonal matrix, so that $A$ is diagonalizable.

Comment: I don't get your point. Can you please make it clearer?I am confused with option 3 and option 4. Since both have rank $4$ which is same as that of $A$.

Comment: You may see my Answer below which shows this possibility.

Comment: Are you familiar with the spectral theorem?

Comment: I don't know spectral theorem sir @amd

Answer (score 1):

** One possibility:**

If $A$ is a symmetric matrix it can always be diagonalized  by an orthogonal matrix $P$ such that $P^{-1}=P^T$ and  $P^{-1} A P= D= P^T A P$. For example:

Let $A=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ its eigen values are $-1,1,1,1$ with eigenvectors as the columns of P
 $P=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 & 1\\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\ 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$ and $D=\begin{pmatrix} -1 & 0 & 0 &0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 &0\\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} =B$